# C# Sendkeys.Send/SendWait Access is Denied (Winform)

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

I created an input simulator wherein you (the user) can create a list of commands, and the application will execute it based on what you'd declared/created. It's about mouse and keyboard inputs.

**DETAILS**

• I use `SendKeys.Send()` or `SendKeys.SendWait()` for keyboard inputs.

• I tried 2 types of execution

```
• Upon opening the app, if you (the user) doesn't press anything in a couple of seconds, the list of commands will execute.
• Threading: The list of commands will run every hour until you stop the app or the thread.
```

**PROBLEM**

• I get an error 'Access is denied' intermittently whenever it tries to do keyboard inputs.

**SCENARIO**

• Task Scheduler (to open the app) (repeat every 1 hour)
or Threading (every hour execution of commands)

• The first run of task scheduler or thread it has no error message, but for the next repeat/next hour it will trigger the error intermittently.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
   at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendInput(Byte[] oldKeyboardState, Queue previousEvents)
   at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(String keys, Control control, Boolean wait)
   at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(String keys)
   at WinformApp.clsAutomation.Start(String& ex)
```

**ADDED DETAILS**

• I added redo the commands/automation for every 2 minutes for 20 maximum tries everytime the error occurs and it's the same thing, the error still occurs, (I use VNCviewer to the PC) but everytime I connect to the pc (for monitoring) the apps run as it should be, no error occurs.

• My app runs as admin.

• I removed sleep/idle time of windows.

• OS: Windows 10

**CODE PART**

```
// Some checking are already done, and this is the part for SendKeys.SendWait

try
{

    process.WaitForInputIdle();
    SendKeys.SendWait(_string);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // Log error message
}
```

Comment: Are you sending to an elevated app?

Comment: What do you mean by elevated app? @PoulBak, anyways, this happens also with notepad when trying to save it (opendialogbox for exact (filename)).

Comment: I meant: An app 'Run as admin'.

Comment: @PoulBak, yes it is.

Comment: Well, you can't send keystrokes from a program run as a normal user to a program run as admin. You can try running your program as admin too.

Comment: @PoulBak, I added new details pertaining to the problem. I already tried running the app as an admin, via properties or requireadminlevel via app.config, still the problem occurs.

Comment: Are you running more than one instance of the app? (I'm totally guessing here, you have have NOT given any code).

Comment: @PoulBak, The app run only one instance at a time, it will automatically close the previous app when it's already running. Also I already updated the post and added the code part for SendWait.

Comment: If **Access Denied** is your only issue there is a similar [question answered here][1] you can try running both the application as Admin or a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't let you run keyboard and mouse emulation when the account is locked.
To get around this, use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon to automatically login to your account on boot (and it will do this without locking your account) and make a task that reboots your computer before each scheduled execution.

Remote Desktop Connection locks your account by default when you end a session and I suspect VNCViewer is doing the same.

Since you use VNCViewer, there may be a way to disable locking of your computer when you end a session, allowing your task to run.

More information:
https://superuser.com/questions/407407/vnc-session-with-locked-screen